# how to show-hide a drop-down element with the options from a different drop-down menu

Tags: angular, dropdown, show-hide, angular-ng-if

I'm assigning roles to the user.

User types are: student, teacher, parent and admin.

So when i select student or teacher as the user from the drop-down. i wanted the class and section drop-down to be enabled. and when admin or parent is selected. the class and section should be disabled.

any help would be great.

I have tried this with radio buttons but drop-downs isn't working for me.

````
<select matInput id="userType" class="fullWidth">
    <option value="" disabled>---Select User---</option>
    <option *ngFor = "let user of users" [ngValue]="user">{{user}</option>
 </select>
  ``` user types are student, teacher, parent and admin```
```below is the drop-down for selecting class if the user type is only student or teacher```
<select matInput id="className" class="fullWidth">
  <option value="" disabled>---Select class---</option> 
  <option *ngFor = "let class of classes"[ngValue]="class">{{class}}</option>
</select>
```class values are 1st, 2nd and 3rd```
````

"i expect the following result
  when student or user is selected from the user type drop down menu. i wanted the class to be enabled. otherwise it should be disabled for all the other user types (which are: admin and parent)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [two-way data binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) to achieve this.

On your component.ts, we shall define the required properties:

```
role: string = undefined;
users : string[] = ['student', 'teacher', 'parent', 'admin'];
```

On your component.html, you will bind the `<select>` element to `role`, which is the model. Then, we use `*ngIf` which will conditionally show/hide the subsequent  based on the selected role. In this scenario, it will only show if the user selects student or teacher.

```
<select matInput [(ngModel)]="role" id="userType" class="fullWidth">
  <option value="" disabled>---Select User---</option>
  <option *ngFor = "let user of users" [ngValue]="user">{{user}}</option>
</select>

<select *ngIf="role === 'student' || role === 'teacher'" matInput id="className" class="fullWidth">
  <option value="" disabled>---Select class---</option> 
  <option *ngFor = "let class of classes"[ngValue]="class">{{class}}</option>
</select>
```

---

EDIT 1: From OP -

Thanks for your reply !!, but the above isn't working for me or maybe I'm doing something wrong. I found the answer though:

```
 <select matInput  id="userType" class="fullWidth" (change)="onChange()" [ngModel]="defaultUser">
            <option value="" disabled>---Select User---</option>
            <option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
            <option value="student">Student</option>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
 </select>
```

and in the .ts file i added the onChange() as :

```
onChange(){
    const userType = document.getElementById("userType");
    const dvClass = document.getElementById("dvClass");
    const dvTeacher = document.getElementById("dvTeacher");
    dvClass.style.display = userType.value == "student" ? "block":"none";
}
```

but i wanted only the student and the teacher to access the class drop-down. im confused with how to add both the users to the above expression in the onChange() (which is : dvClass.style.display = userType.value == "student" ? "block":"none";)

---

Edit 2:

Here are my proposed changes based on your update. Similar to my initial code, I have made use of 2-way binding. However, I have used the [titlecase pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/TitleCasePipe) to transform the values of the options to have the first letter capitalised (instead of manually defining it).

```
<select matInput [(ngModel)]="role" id="userType" class="fullWidth">
  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>---Select User---</option>
  <option *ngFor = "let user of users" [ngValue]="user">{{user | titlecase}}</option>
</select>

<br>

<select *ngIf="role === 'student' || role === 'teacher'" matInput id="className" class="fullWidth">
  <option value="" disabled>---Select class---</option> 
  <option *ngFor = "let class of classes"[ngValue]="class">{{class}}</option>
</select>
```

[Updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sa35xb?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html).

Comment: This isn't working. i found out the solution though.

Comment: @krishnaram Yes, you are right, the above code is not 100% correct since it is only a rough sketch, but the idea/algorithm is there. All the best with learning Angular!

Comment: thanks for the effort and yes as you said. i might be wrong. can you help me with the updated question please? @wentjun

Comment: Hmmm.. What you want to achieve, is to only show the class drop-down if the user has selected only 'teacher' or 'student', right? If the user selects something else, the class dropdown will be hidden? Perhaps it is something like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sa35xb?file=app/select-value-binding-example.html

Comment: this is exactly what i wanted @wentjun. Thanks heaps. Can we connect for further communication?

Comment: @krishnaram sure, I will ping you on stackoverflow chat. I will also update my answer to reflect the changes from my code